# Order BY turns a 30ms query into a 7120ms query. Known performance issue?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a User table with 1m records:

```
User (id, fname, lname, deleted_at, guest)
```

I have the following query which is being run against a postgres 9.1 db:

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (SUBSTRING(lower(fname), 1, 1) = 's') 
ORDER BY guest = false, fname ASC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Using pgAdmin 3, this SQL is taking **7120ms** to return 25 rows. If I remove the 'ORDER BY guest = false, fname ASC' the query takes just **31ms**.

I have the following indexes:

```
add_index "users", ["fname"], :name => "index_users_on_fname"
add_index "users", ["guest", "fname"], :name => "index_users_on_guest_and_fname"
add_index "users", ["deleted_at"], :name => "index_users_on_deleted_at"
add_index "users", ["guest"], :name => "index_users_on_guest"
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

**UPDATED with Explain**

```
"Limit  (cost=43541.55..43541.62 rows=25 width=1612) (actual time=1276.777..1276.783 rows=25 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=43541.55..43558.82 rows=6905 width=1612) (actual time=1276.775..1276.777 rows=25 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: ((NOT guest)), fname"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 37kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..43346.70 rows=6905 width=1612) (actual time=5.143..1272.563 rows=475 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND pubic_profile_visible AND ((fname)::text ~~ 's%'::text))"
"Total runtime: 1276.967 ms"
```

Comment: Can you please post explain or even better explain analyze on your query to see what the query plan is?

Comment: Updated... Is that what you needed?

Comment: `User (id, fname, lname, deleted_at, guest)` Please give us the *real* table definition, including keys, constraints and indices.

Comment: indexes on boolean fields don't do anything IIRC. Is it faster with fname in the order clause?

Comment: Did you mention the version of PostgreSQL somewhere?

Comment: Just realized I don't even need the ORDER BY guest = false

Comment: Even still, with just the ORDER BY fname ASC, the performance issue is still there

Comment: Just realized that with "ORDER BY fname ASC" performance is very slow as mentioned above. But if I change that to "ORDER BY fname DESC" performance is very fast, 100ms. Why would that be?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter PostgreSQL v9.1

Comment: It is the top-N heapsort at work + the particular pattern in your data.

Comment: @ColdTree If you get different performance with reverse ordering, it can be worth creating a reverse index, eg `CREATE INDEX ... ON table(field DESC)`. As always, every index you add slows down inserts and updates, so only create an index if it's more benefit than cost, avoid creating unused/unnecessary indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, since PostgreSQL 9.1 you can use [`left()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) to simplify the expression:

```
substring(lower(fname), 1, 1)
lower(left(fname, 1)) -- equivalent, but simpler and faster
```

Also slightly faster to take the first character *before* casting to lower case.
Next, clean up the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  deleted_at IS NULL
AND    lower(left(fname, 1)) = 's'
ORDER  BY guest DESC NULLS LAST, fname
LIMIT  25 OFFSET 0;
```

[`guest DESC NULLS LAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) results in the same as `guest = FALSE`, just without calculating a new value for every row.
Next, create this [multi-column partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html):

```
CREATE INDEX users_multi_idx
ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)), guest DESC NULLS LAST, fname)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Run

```
ANALYZE users;
```

Or, even better, [`CLUSTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) (if you don't have more important queries requiring a different order) -  and *then* `ANALYZE`:

```
CLUSTER users using users_multi_idx;
```

And it will be way faster than anything you tried before. Because now, the query reads rows from the index sequentially and the table has been physically rewritten in the same order, resulting in only few page hits ...

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I'm going to give this a try. I need to figure out how to add a multi-column index to rails

Comment: @ColdTree: You can just run the raw SQL. It's a one-time operation.

Comment: That's incredible. Thank you!

Comment: Erwin, quick follow-up question. Is there a way to make this work for also being able to query for all non A-Z characters. I had been using User.where("fname ~ E'^[^a-zA-Z].*') and notice now that using "lower(left(fname, 1)) ~ E'^[^a-zA-Z].*" errors. Thanks

Comment: The query does return the non A-Z with the follow "lower(left(fname, 1)) ~ E'^[^a-zA-Z].*'" however the performance is lost. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: @ColdTree: If you are going to use regular expressions this kind of index is not always usable. If you want to lump all non A-Z into one category, you could create an IMMUTABLE function that lumps all of them together (for instance to `0`) and create an index using this function. There is also `COLLATION` and operator classes ... Way to much for a comment. I suppose you ask another question.

Comment: good call. I added a new question here. Feedback appreciated. Thanks --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906264/how-to-create-an-index-to-lump-all-non-a-z-characters

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you could stand to have some better indexing here; You are filtering based on the `deleted_at` field, and then sorting on the `guest` field, but those fields are not in a common index. Ignoring your other `WHERE` clause for the moment, you seem to be causing the engine to dig through all the records, or just individually check each record for it's `guest` value; I don't see how your index with `guest` in it could be helping.

If you included the `guest` field in an index along with the `deleted_at` field (the latter being first), you might get some benefit there.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance your problem is the need to fully evaluate the where clause, in order to get all (not just the 25 first rows) you need to order by after... try adding a column containing `substring(lower(fname), 1, 1))` let's name it `s` for now and adding an index on `deleted_at, s`, or if this is these are the only values you'll be formulating this where with an index on `(deleted is null), (s = 's')`.

You could use a trigger to keep the `s` column up to date.

To make it temporarily faster you could just rewrite `substring(lower(fname), 1, 1))` to `lower(substring(fname, 1, 1))` or if postgresql has this syntax `lower(fname[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

If there are few distinct values in a column then an index on that column is not of much value. That is the case with a boolean column.

I would test creating a partial index on `SUBSTRING(lower(fname), 1, 1)`

```
CREATE INDEX users_substr_null_ix ON users (SUBSTRING(lower(fname), 1, 1))
WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

And also test a partial index on fname:

```
CREATE INDEX users_fname_not_guest_ix ON users (fname)
WHERE not guest;
```

Or even better

```
CREATE INDEX users_substr_null__not_guest_ix ON users (SUBSTRING(lower(fname), 1, 1), fname)
WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL and not guest;
```

Comment: If you exclude the guests from the partial index you are going one step to far, and the index is not usable for the query any more. They need to be included, just sorted.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ok you are right. In case you care I uploaded a [50k rows table](http://www.2shared.com/document/VzDHZutm/users_table.html) for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I have similar real life (test-)databases I can use. But may be useful for someone else.