# Faster search for records where 1st character of field doesn't match [A-Za-z]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I currently have the following:

```
User (id, fname, lname, deleted_at, guest)
```

I can query for a list of user's by their `fname` initial like so:

```
User Load (9.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (lower(left(fname, 1)) = 's') ORDER BY fname ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

This is fast thanks to the following index:

```
  CREATE INDEX users_multi_idx
  ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)), fname)
  WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

What I want to do now is be able to query for all Users that do not start with the letter's A-Z. I got this to work like so:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (lower(left(fname, 1)) ~ E'^[^a-zA-Z].*') ORDER BY fname ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

But the problem is this query is very slow and does not appear to be using the index to speed up the first query. Any suggestions on how I can elegantly make the 2nd query (non a-z) faster?

I'm using Postgres 9.1 with rails 3.2

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for showing your versions. It might be helpful if you pasted `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of both queries to http://explain.depesz.com/ and linked to them here (you should do that for all performance questions), though in this case it's reasonably clear the 1st is using an index that the 2nd can't.

Comment: Please link to previous, related questions when they exist, it helps make answering easier.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Updated answer</sup>
[Preceding question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12905312/939860)

My first idea idea (index with [`text_pattern_ops`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-opclass.html)) did not work with the regular expression in my tests. Better rewrite your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE lower(left(fname, 1)) < 'a' COLLATE "C"
OR    lower(left(fname, 1)) > 'z' COLLATE "C"
ORDER  BY fname
LIMIT  25 OFFSET 0;
```

Besides from these expressions being faster generally, your regular expression also had capital letters in it, which did not match the index with `lower()`. And the trailing characters were pointless while comparing to a single char.

And use this index:

```
CREATE INDEX users_multi_idx
ON users (lower(left(fname, 1)) COLLATE "C", fname)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

The [`COLLATE "C"`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) part is optional and only contributes a very minor gain in performance. It's purpose is to reset collation rules to default posix collation, which just uses byte order and is generally faster. Useful, where collation rules are not relevant anyway.

**If** you create the index with it, only queries that match the collation can use it. So you might *just skip it* to simplify things if performance is not your paramount requirement.

Comment: Thanks but that results w an error: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
LINE 1: ...deleted_at IS NULL) AND ( lower(left(fname, 1)) < "a" COLLAT...

Comment: @ColdTree: Replace the double quotes around "a" with single quotes: -> **`'a'`**.

Comment: Nice that worked. I see in the rails log the query User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (lower(left(fname, 1)) < 'a' COLLATE "C" OR lower(left(fname, 1)) > 'z' COLLATE "C") ORDER BY fname ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0 ----- However the performance gain was not achieved. Still about 1356ms

Comment: @ColdTree: Got no more time atm, sorry.

Comment: No worries, also, noticing it's not returning all the expected results just a few.

Comment: @ColdTree Whenever you're talking performance, post `explain analyze` results - you can paste them to http://explain.depesz.com/ and link to them in comments. If you don't show the numbers then everyone's hand-waving in the dark. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @ErwinBrandstetter's general solution, PostgreSQL supports [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html). You can say:

```
CREATE INDEX users_nonalphanumeric_not_deleted_key
ON users (id)
WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (lower(left(fname, 1)) ~ E'^[^a-zA-Z].*');
```

This index won't help for any other lookups, but it will precompute the answer for this particular query. This technique is often useful for queries that return a small, predefined subset from a much larger table, since the resulting index will disregard the vast majority of the table and contain only the rows of interest.

Comment: Note that your query will need to use the index condition almost verbatim; the query planner isn't very smart about matching equivalent conditions. For example if you reversed the two clauses around the `AND` the planner probably wouldn't use the index. I find it helpful to wrap the index condition in an SQL function, then use that SQL function wherever I want to refer to the index, since that makes it easy for the planner to match the two.